# How to know the available virtual memory inside an application

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory, malloc

As the title asks,

Is it possible to know the currently available virtual memory
    (which is allocatable by malloc/mmap) inside an application by
    programmatically?

What I'm looking for is some kind of a function

```
unsigned int free_mem();
```

which will return the size of memory allocatable by malloc or mmap.

Comment: You could always read `/proc/meminfo`

Comment: are you sure that's what you need? the amount of free memory does not mean a continuous block of free memory. Say if you have 100 bytes of free memory, that does not mean you can use that to allocate an array which requires 90 bytes. The memory is divided in chunks of variable sizes.

Comment: @Joachim No, what I meant is the virtual memory for a process.

Comment: @Pandrei Yes it is what I need. I'm not using it for allocating memory. I'm using it for accounting the free memory size, because I need to do some memory management for several modules which consume lot of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are explicitly talking about available *virtual* memory, you need to find the parts of the virtual address space which are currently unallocated. Segment information is available in `proc/self/smaps`.

However, the size of the virtual address space is determined by the cpu your program is executing on. This is *not* 64 bits on a 64 bit processor, but can be determined by `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "address sizes"` which yields

```
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
address sizes   : 42 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
```

on the VM I am currently testing it on.

Note that the total amount of available virtual address space is different from the largest amount allocatable in one go, since you can only mmap a sequential amount of memory.

For example consider the simple case of 32 bit pointers with the following segments:

```
00020000-000204ff /usr/bin/executable
00030000-0003ffff [heap]
7ff80000-7ff9ffff [stack]
```

In this case the largest continuous segment is `7ffA000-ffffffff`, but the total amount of available virtual memory is only slightly less than 4 GB.

Note also that `malloc` may be able to satisfy your request without requiring more virtual memory by reusing already requested pages. The amount available this way depends on a many things (size of the allocation or allocations, state of the heap) and cannot be queried in any portable way. This holds double if someone [`LD_PRELOAD`s another `malloc` implementation](http://locklessinc.com/install_linux.shtml).