# Obtain how much memory is available (roughly) before malloc

Tags: c++, c, tcmalloc

Can I obtain how much memory is available (roughly) before a `malloc()`? I need to adjust some internal variables before doing a `malloc()/new` because performing a `malloc()` and then checking and deleting is not feasible.

(FYI, I am asking about glibc and tcmalloc's `malloc()`, but any other `malloc()` is also OK)

Comment: have a look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process

Comment: What is your operating system? On Linux and Windows, there are many previous questions such as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513505/how-to-get-available-memory-c-g/26639774

Comment: [sysinfo()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysinfo.2.html).freeram

Comment: This depends on your OS, there is no standard library function for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know the available virtual memory inside an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497840/how-to-know-the-available-virtual-memory-inside-an-application)

Comment: Even if you could, how do you know the same memory is still available when you `malloc`? Just try to allocate what you need. You have to check the result anyway. Oh, and why is this tagged with two different languages?

Comment: That's an XY problem. If your current design has to check in advance, it's wrong; change it.